# Statistical test for multiple biological replicates

Tags: anova

I am doing an experiment whereby I have 4 different conditions.  Within each condition, I do 4-7 technical replicates (cell counts in 4-7 high powered fields).  I have also repeated the experiment 3 times (3 biological replicate (rats)).  What test will compare the 4 different conditions, but will also take into account the variation between biological replicates?  I am trying to do this in graphpad prism 5.0.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you'll need to do a **two-way analysis of variance** to me. I'm assuming the 'technical replicates' are 3 repeats of the same measurement procedure in the same rat with the same condition, and all the rats are subjected to all the conditions. The rats are then a 'blocking' factor, and the condition is your 'treatment' factor.

My only niggling doubt is: how did you decide how many technical replicates to do in each case?